# React Native : Change targeted sdk version for App store upload

Tags: iphone, ios13

In App Store I am trying to upload my app but I'm getting a warning i.e. mentioned below:

**Warning**:

SDK Version Issue: app built with the iOS 12.1 SDK must be updated with the iOS 13 SDK or later, included in Xcode 11 or later

From Jun 2020, new apps must target at least iOS 13.0

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the deployment target in your xcode. In your xcode project navigate to the **General** section, and select deployment target to the required version i.e 13

[image]

in case your xcode does not have the required sdk version in the dropdown, you need to update the xcode.

Comment: Thanks! As mentioned I have updated the xcode version to the latest(11.4.1) bcz my previous version of xcode does not have the required sdk version in dropdown. By updating xcode  here I can able to run my code successfully in my local simulator and physical device.

We are using Azure build pipeline to deploy the app to app center. But, after distributing the app and downloaded from App center results in crashing of my app on clicking login button in home page. 

FYI: I have replicated the Xcode version manually(11.4.1) even in my build pipeline definations. 
Awaiting for your response !